# c# excel write text with multicolor into the same cell

Tags: c#, excel

I want to write text into a excel cell with the diffrent conditions . For example if the selected value is red excel cell text might be red .I am using enum to define color which name is ExcelColorType But it doesn't work . What am i missing ?

There is a some source code below .

```cs
private static void ExcelSatirGuncelle(Worksheet worksheet, string message, int rowNumber, ExcelColorType colorType)
{
    var cell = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 7];

    string values = cell.Value2;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(values))
        values = "";        

    cell.Font.Bold = true;
    cell.ColumnWidth = 200;
    cell.Value2 += message + Environment.NewLine;

    cell.Characters(values.Length, message.Length).Font.Color = colorType== ExcelColorType.Yesil ? Color.Green : Color.Red;

    worksheet.Cells.VerticalAlignment = XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
    worksheet.Cells.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
}
```

Actually this code is working in the runtime . But All text is being green . I have several if condition color might be Color.Red but all text being green .

Comment: which Excel library are you using?

Comment: How are you testing? What is the object ExcelColorType?  Is it a custom enum?  I would try simplifying your condition to check everything outside of your conditional.  For example, I'd make a column of numbers that are either 1 or 2.  Then change the conditional to ...Font.Color = cell.Value == 1 : Color.Green : Color.Red (or something to this effect).

Comment: I am using  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library.

Comment: Do you want same `cell` or same `column`?

Comment: I just run project to see some result . Yes ExcelColorType is a custom enum that includes just Green and Red property. I am using some text for testing . For example i am adding cell.value2 += "Green color triggered" to the if scope. When i do that both conditions are triggered when the condition occured but color is staying green i want it in the same cell

Comment: Two things - your Characters argument may not make sense.  Ie - values = "****".  Message = "***".  Value2 after the concatenation = "*****"  values.Length = 4.  message.Length = 3.  You're calling cell.Characters(4,3).  Do you really want Characters(4,7)?  Next, you have no logic that would turn any text red if you pass ExcelColorType.Yesil as an argument.  You never evaluate cells outside of inset of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
            ((Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 7]).Value = message;
            Range cell = (Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 7];

            if (colorType.Equals("Green"))
            {
                cell.Characters[0, message.Length].Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Green);
            }
            else
            {
                cell.Characters[0, message.Length].Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
            }
```